# Limit results to distinct system name when multiple records returned 

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

This is running on SQL Server 2000

Background: when a new server is brought onto the network, it will pass through a series of status (stages) such as (loading, testing, configuring, production, etc) were production is the final step (not every server in the report will be in production so this bit of information may be a moot point).

I inherited this so if there are any questions, I'll answer them as best as I can.  I'm trying to run a query to get the latest status of all the servers during a specific time frame.  My query is currently returning every status for the server and I only need the current status and that is where I need your help.

The query I'm working with is as follows:

```
SELECT SD.ProjectName, SD.SystemName, SD.Status, H.history_id
FROM dbo.SI_SystemDetail AS SD 
INNER JOIN dbo.SI_Projects AS P ON SD.ProjectName = P.ProjectName 
INNER JOIN dbo.SI_StatusHistory AS H ON SD.SystemName = H.SystemName   
WHERE     
    (P.Cancelled = 'N') 
    AND (P.Platform LIKE '%ibm%') 
    AND ('20110101' <= CONVERT(varchar(8), H.EffectiveDate, 112)) 
    AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), H.EffectiveDate, 112) <= '20111111')   
ORDER BY 
     H.history_id DESC, SD.SystemName, SD.ContactSBCuid, SD.ActualLiveDAte DESC, 
     SD.ProjectName, SD.SystemType, H.EffectiveDate`
```

This will return several duplicates for systemname but I only need one and that should correspond with the highest history_id number.  For example, lets say there is a server named:

```
Server Name        Status       History_ID  
Server01           Loading      1001
Server01           Configuring  1081
Server01           Testing      1101
Server01           Production   1451
Server02           Loading      1002
Server02           Configuring  1083
Server02           Testing      1104
Server02           Failed       1455
```

I would just need the following results returned:

```
Server Name        Status       History_ID  
Server01           Production   1451
Server02           Failed       1455
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: @marc-s Thanks for the clean up.  I tried but it was just getting worse.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED:

```
SELECT SD.ProjectName, SD.SystemName, SD.Status, H.history_id 
FROM dbo.SI_SystemDetail AS SD 
INNER JOIN dbo.SI_Projects AS P 
  ON SD.ProjectName = P.ProjectName 
INNER JOIN dbo.SI_StatusHistory AS H 
  ON SD.SystemName = H.SystemName
WHERE (P.Cancelled = 'N') AND (P.Platform LIKE '%ibm%') AND ('20110101' <= CONVERT(varchar(8), H.EffectiveDate, 112)) AND (CONVERT(varchar(8), H.EffectiveDate, 112) <= '20111111')
AND history_ID = (
  Select max(history_ID) 
  FROM SI_Status_History iSH 
  where iSH.SystemName = SD.SystemName)
ORDER BY H.history_id DESC, SD.SystemName, SD.ContactSBCuid, SD.ActualLiveDAte DESC, SD.ProjectName, SD.SystemType, H.EffectiveDate
```

Comment: I knew it needed a subquery but I didn't know where to place it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just implemented your solution and test it and it was perfect.  Thanks again.